# Recover data from a dropped/truncated MySQL table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, recovery

I just spend a few hours putting together a table full of data, and just decided to drop a WP installation in the same database. I expected WordPress to leave my table as it was and simply add the WP_* tables, but apparently the install wiped my database before installing the wordpress tables.

I have full access to the server root. Is there any way for me to recover this table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but that can't be done.  Once a table is truncated or dropped everything is gone.

The only way to get it back would be recovering the database files from the disk, but that is not very reliable. To do that, you first have to find out where the MySQL's data files are (see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=443371)), then try using a [file recovery tool](http://www.google.com/search?q=file+recovery+tool) to get them back. Good luck.

Another one who learns to back up the hard way.

[image: Click me]

Comment: Is there a decent chance or recovering the database files in one piece? It only just got overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If tables were MyISAM, then I agree with NullUserException - you can't recover the tables. Well, the chance is very slim.

If InnoDB - check out my presentation on slideshare - there is a tool to extract records from raw bytes stream - percona data recovery toolkit. There are examples in the presentation, your scenario is pretty much typical.

**UPDATE**: Data recovery toolkit moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb)